# Calling a method within Main

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to call a method from outside of the main method and I'm stumped on how to go about doing it. I may be going about this the wrong way. For instance, I'd like the user to enter in a temperature in Fahrenheit and then call the fahrenheitToCelsius method to do the conversion and return the converted temperature.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Converter {

// conversions
private static final double GRAMS_PER_OUNCE = 28.3495;
private static final double CENTIMETERS_PER_FEET = 30.48;

public static double fahrenheitToCelsius (double f) {

    return (f - 32) / 1.8;
}

public static double feetToCentimeters (double feet) {

    return feet * CENTIMETERS_PER_FEET;
}

public static double ouncesToGrams (double ounces) {

    return ounces * GRAMS_PER_OUNCE;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number in Fahrenheit: ");
    System.out.print(in.nextDouble());

}
}
```

Comment: `Converter.[what_method_you want to_call](your_input);`

Comment: I've tried what Bejasc has suggested but it's throwing a "cannot find symbol" error on var.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I suggest you give this page a read https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @Bejasc Yes you are right, but I also suggest that you not waste peoples time by posting wrong answers when there are adequate correct duplicate answers

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for the tips, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter a number in Fahrenheit: ");
   double far = in.nextDouble();
   double cel = fahrenheitToCelsius (far); 
   System.out.println (cel); 
}
```

Like this?

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of my earlier answer above.
Could you explain what your answer does differently?

Comment: @Bejasc I guess it compiles for a start

Comment: @Bejasc i believe you do not need the System.out.print(in.nextDouble()); ....  but could be wrong :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat You might find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @Kattie Not only *not needed* but will not even compile

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks